# unable to install office 365 pro plus

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, office365

I've purchased 365 pro plus, while installing I get error message

[image]

found a some tips [Here](https://www.kapilarya.com/office-ran-into-a-problem-because-its-system-service-is-disabled), but when I open Services I get **office source engine** is giving error

[image]

How can I fix it any suggestions are strongly welcome.

Comment: It's not giving you an error, your reading that incorrectly, the description is is improperly set, it's also broken, but that's besides the point.

Comment: Use the uninstaller, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US, then try again.  Yes; realize it's not installed, but that service, isn't properly configured which can only be done by the office installer.